# Проблема сериализации данных JSON

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Возникла проблема с отправкой данных, полученных из базы данных.

Сам код отправки

```
@app.route('/ajax/post_list', methods=['GET'])
def post_list():
from model import Post, Comments
if request.method == 'GET':
    posts = list(Post.query.all())
    cross = []
    for i in range(len(posts)):
        cross.append(posts[i])
return jsonify(cross)
```

Модель

```
class Post(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
title = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=False, nullable=False)
text = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False, nullable=False)

def __init__(self, title, text):
    self.title = title
    self.text = text

def __repr__(self):
    return '%r , %r' % (self.title, self.text)
```

Возникает ошибка

> TypeError: Object of type 'Post' is not JSON serializable

Не могу понять почему возникает данная ошибка, ведь у cross тип list. Можете объяснить в чем проблема, и направление для ее решение. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Но внутри-то этого list'а лежат несовместимые с JSON данные! С JSON совместимы только: None, bool, int, float, str, tuple, list, dict. Позаботьтесь о том, чтобы внутри list'а лежали только эти типы. Post в список поддерживаемых JSON'ом типов очевидно не входит

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [jsonify a SQLAlchemy result set in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102754)